# npm install modifying registry url

Tags: tfs, npm-install, azure-artifacts

I'm hosting a npm registry on a TFS 2017 server, with the [Package Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/package/index) extension. Its hostname has a single part, `dnsXxx`, without any extension like `.com`, and is configured on the port `8080`. I'm using a `.npmrc` file to define this repository for packages in the scope `@abc`:

```
@abc:registry=http://dnsXxx:8080/tfs/.../npm/registry/
@abc:proxy=null
@abc:always-auth=true
```

When I tried to install one of its packages, using a command like `npm i @abc/mypackage`, from the folder containing the `.npmrc` file, the command is taking a long time to finally fail with `npm ERR! 503 Service Unavailable: @abc/mypackage@...`.

Using WireShark, I figured out that the url called by npm has been modified, I guess "normalized" that way: `GET http://www.dnsXxx.com/tfs/.../npm/registry/@abc%2fmypackage HTTP/1.1`, resulting in:

- Port is missing
- `www.` host prefix and `.com` host extension have been added improperly

If I call the fixed url in a browser, `http://dnsXxx:8080/tfs/.../npm/registry/@abc%2fmypackage`, I get the expected JSON answer.

Does anyone see a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was due to the entreprise proxy, called even with `proxy=null` in the `.npmrc` file. It's the proxy that is reformating the hostname. When I switched to the server IP address, updating the auth token, it has finally succeeded:

```
@abc:registry=http://10.x.y.z:8080/tfs/.../npm/registry/
@abc:always-auth=true

; Treat this auth token like a password. Do not share it with anyone, including Microsoft support. This token expires on or before 05-Feb-18.
; begin auth token
//10.x.y.z:8080/tfs/.../npm/registry/:_authToken=...    
//10.x.y.z:8080/tfs/.../npm/:_authToken=...  
; end auth token
```

Other option: using a [FQN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_name) for the server name (xxx.yyy.zzz instead of just xxx) which won't be changed by the proxy (into www.xxx.com).

Comment: I have the same issue of `ERR! 503 Service Unavailable` on some dependencies of my project even though I correctly set `registry=http://srvnexus/nexus/repository/npm-all/` in the project `.npmrc` file .. Do you have some suggestions plz ?

Comment: @ghassen: the issue is due to the "short dns" name, `srvnexus`. Use a long name instead (if possible in your network), `srvnexus.local` for instance. Else, try with IP address.

Comment: Coool ! It works really with the IP address of nexus ;) Thank you so much

Comment: @ghassen: what about marking the question/answer as useful with a "+1" ? ;)

Comment: I have done it for  the comment .. I thought it would be the same .. but now I did it for the response ;) Bonne journée